# Infinite array as Jenkins parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to create a Jenkins job, where the Job iterates through an array of values. The number of array items are not fixed, it may vary in subsequent builds.

For example, my job iterates through the following set of array values:

ServerName: server1.example.com IP: 1.1.1.1 user: Homer

ServerName: server2.example.com IP: 2.2.2.2 user: Bart

.

.

ServerName: serverN.example.com IP: x.x.x.x user: Ned

The job runs it first iteration with values {ServerName: server1.example.com, IP: 1.1.1.1, user: Homer}, second iteration with values {ServerName: server2.example.com, IP: 2.2.2.2, user: Bart}, etc. to N iterations.

Here, important point is N is not fixed.

I had a look into the extended choice parameter with JSON/groovy, but could not find a solution for the varied number of array items problem.

IS there a plugin which can be used in this scenario, and if so, what is the correct usage?

Answer (score 0):

I use a `String Parameter` and in my pipeline script I use a `script` block to split the string, it splits on newlines or just spaces by default which was all I needed. It looks like you would need a special split character, note that groovy supports regular expressions for splitting as [shown here](http://grails.asia/groovy-split). Maybe you could use a `|` character and split on that,

```
"{ServerName: server.example.com, IP: 1.1.1.1, user: Bart1}|{ServerName: server2.example.com, IP: 2.2.2.2, user: Bart2}"
```

Then you could do

```
script {
    def list = "${StringParamName}".split('|')

    // Can NOT use `for (var_item in list)` because of NotSerializableException
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        def item = list[i]
        // Do work with "${item}"
    }
}
```